# What causes this 'Solitaire' effect in Qt (PyQt)?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

[image]

What is causing this 'Solitaire' effect when dragging widgets around and how to fix it? It goes away when the screen is resized or anything changes but it's super annoying nonetheless. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QSizePolicy


# Draggable Frame
class Pod(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred))
        self.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        QtGui.QLabel('Drag Me', self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            curr_pos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
            global_pos = event.globalPos()
            diff = global_pos - self.__mouseMovePos
            new_pos = self.mapFromGlobal(curr_pos + diff)
            self.move(new_pos)
            self.__mouseMovePos = global_pos

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()
                return


# Base Widget
class Dock(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.set_bg_color()

    # Set background red
    def set_bg_color(self):
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor(240, 0, 0, 127))
        self.setPalette(p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dock = Dock()
    dock.resize(800, 600)
    pod1 = Pod(dock)
    pod1.move(300, 300)
    dock.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I know I'm stating the obvious, but the screen is repainted when it's resized. You probably need to trigger a partial or full repaint somehow when the widget moves.

Comment: @MillieSmith That was same conclusion I was coming to, I just wasn't sure if there was a better way instead of repainting the screen all the time, Thanks for the input.

Comment: It's a bit of a weird combination of things to use to do this. Have you considered using a `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` and drawing in that? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It's probably caused by the alpha component of the background color.